# Are there any live Pinax demos out there?

Tags: python, django, pinax, demo

Pinax package wraps some pretty fancy stuff. Are there any live demos out there that one could browse without installing/setting up Pinax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is mention of [sites built with pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/sites/) at their project page itself. You may want to choose any of the site, create an account and login to see their customization page. This may perhaps give you some idea.

Answer (score -1):

There used to be [cloud27](http://cloud27.com/). It was their official demo. But it's disabled for some reason.